# Omission of "by" before gerund in imperative sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, gerunds

I have been thinking about the use of "by" and its omission in certain situations, especially before gerund in imperative sentences. I did find the other entry (*“by” before the gerund, when is needed*) relating to the subject, but it did not match my question.

Examples to clarify what I refer to:

- "Create a new image file by using Paint."
- "Create a new image file using Paint."

The first one feels to me as the only good option, because at least in my mind the second option makes it more difficult to understand it as fast. When I read it, it takes a while for me to understand if the meaning is "create a new image file BY using Paint" or "create a new image file WHICH uses Paint" (doesn't make much sense though in this context, but it's where my mind automatically goes). However, in my current job, I continuously encounter these kinds of sentences which almost always omit the "by", so I wonder if both of these forms are grammatically correct? Also, if they are both grammatically correct, is one of them instinctively easier to understand or is it just me who has problems with the second one?

(Edit.) Is there some kind of rule or other kind of mental tool I could use, so that it would be easier to estimate when "by" can/should be omitted?

Comment: Deletions very frequently lead to loss of precision (cf image file compression). But with your example, the prepositionless variant is hardly less clear, and in most contexts would be the preferred version. Image files don't make use of applications. Situations where including  'by' _just might_ be preferred are where the application  'Paint' is being showcased, highlighted. Or where the particular method is being highlighted.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning and they are both means adjuncts. The difference is syntactic: in the second example, the gerund-participial clause functions as an adjunct itself rather than being governed by the preposition "by", as in the first.

Comment: How much better the sentence becomes if you omit "by" depends on the gerund. "Using" suggests "by", so you might perhaps consider "using" to be not much worse than "by using". But now consider these examples: "Complete the action by clicking 'OK'." "Paste the selected text by typing Ctrl-V." Do you think they would still be good if you remove the 'by'?

Comment: Rosie's question is either for Edwin or Bill? I would prefer using "by" in all these kinds of sentences, because I feel it makes it much more clearer. My example with the image file and Paint was to illustrate the problem, but the real-life examples I encounter are more typically something like: "These metrics are provided as a visualization of the activity monitoring counters using dashboards." When I try to estimate whether "by" or "which" should go somewhere in there or not, I can almost feel my brain start to fry! I guess I was hoping for a rule I could utilize.

Comment: @RosieF I think it's got less to do with the gerund than the complexity and exclusivity of the action. You could say "Make up a sponge cake mixture using eggs and self-raising flour" which is an extensive and incompletely defined instruction but then say  "First break the eggs into a bowl and beat them by using an electric whisk". The second instruction is shorter, more complete, and is an implied part of the first instruction. You might say 'using an electric whisk' but you certainly would not say 'by using self-raising flour'.

Comment: Including the _by_ in these contexts seems to suggest the existence of a list of other manners that this manner is being selected from. I.e, _Mix by using an electric beater (not a hand mixer)_.